# Question about closed sets in the proof of Banach-Steinhaus theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't understand a few sentences in the proof of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem. In the beginning of the proof we select sets $A_k=\{x\in X | \|T_n x\|\leq k\}$. Then the author shows that $A_k$ are closed:

> For any $x\in \bar{A_k}$ there is a sequence $(x_j)$ in $A_k$ converging to $x$. This means that for every fixed $n$ we have $\|T_n x_j\|\leq k$ and obtain $\|T_n x\|\leq k$ because $T_n$ is continuous and so is the norm. Hence  $x\in A_k$, and $A_k$ is closed.

Could you help me to clarify the following points:

1) How does the fact $x\in A_k$ follow from the continuity of $T_n$ and boundedness of norms?

2) Why do we need to show that $A_k$ are closed? How is the property used later on in the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for a bounded operator $T$ and $x_j\to x$,
$$
|\,\|Tx_j\|-\|Tx\|\,|\leq \|Tx_j-Tx\|
$$
(triangle inequality). So if $T$ is boudned then $Tx_j-Tx\to0$ and so $\|Tx_j\|\to \|Tx\|$.

As for the $A_k$ closed, usually one uses Baire's Category Theorem, that says that a if a countable union of closed sets equals the whole metric space, then one of them has nonempty interior.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What I'm a little confused about is why the $\leq$ bound $\|T_n x\|\leq k$ is preserved when $\|Tx_j\|\to \|Tx\|$.

Comment: If numbers $r_j\to r $ and $r_j\leq k $ for all $j $, then $r\leq k $.